# Solve system of differential equations using integrating combination

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, systems-of-equations

I am trying to solve **this** system of differential equations:
$$
\left\{ 
\begin{array}{c}
\dot{x} = -xy^2+x+y \\ 
\dot{y} = -x-y+x^2y 
\end{array}
\right.
$$
I am trying to find integrating combination to solve this equation. Could you please provide it?

I will provide an example:

System:
$$
\left\{ 
\begin{array}{c}
x' = \frac{x}{z} \\ 
y' = -\frac{x}{y} 
\end{array}
\right.
$$

an integrating combination for it:
$$
\frac{dz}{dy} = -\frac{z}{y}
$$

it was get from the system by combinating its participants.

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: @Klangen I tried to multiply by $x$ the first equation and by $y$ the second one

Comment: Perhaps, the coefficient of $y$ in the second Eq. could be +.

Comment: @DrZafarAhmedDSc, thanks, I'll try this out

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**A possibility:** when we change $-y$ to $+y$ in Equation (2) such that we have to solve  $$\dot x=-xy^2+x+y~~~(1)~~~~~ \mbox{and}~~~~~~ \dot y=-x+y+x^2y~~~(2).$$
Multiply (1) by $x$ and (2) by $y$ and add both the equations as:
$$x\dot x+y\dot y=x^2+y^2 \Rightarrow \frac{1}{2} \frac{d}{dt} (x^2+y^2)=(x^2+y^2) \Rightarrow \int \frac{d(x^2+y^2)}{x^2+y^2}=2 \int  dt. $$
We get the solution as  $$\log (x^2+y^2)=2t+C \Rightarrow x^2+y^2=D~ e^{2t}.$$